# docker stop command hanging to remove stale containers

Tags: windows, docker, containers, azure-service-fabric

I have in excess of 20 odd running containers which i wish to remove. Docker stop command is hanging and gives no output. tried docker rm command also but it says cannot remove a running container. tried docker container prune command also but no good. 
these are windows containers deployed on service fabric cluster. Nodes are windows server 2019 core (no GUI).
docker and service fabric installed on the nodes. as service fabric cluster is installed so docker engine service is stopped.

1) docker stop container_ID - does not work

2) docker stop $(docker container ls -aq) - does not work

3) navigated to C:\programdata\docker\windowsfilter and removed the container.

4) again performed a docker inspect container id of the removed container in step 3 and it gives results.

5) not sure how to remove these ghost containers.

```
PS C:\ProgramData\docker\windowsfilter> docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Enterprise
 Version:           19.03.1
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.12.5
 Git commit:        f660560464
 Built:             07/25/2019 20:59:52
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Enterprise
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.1
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.24)
  Go version:       go1.12.5
  Git commit:       f660560464
  Built:            07/25/2019 20:57:41
  OS/Arch:          windows/amd64
  Experimental:     false
```

```
PS C:\ProgramData\docker\windowsfilter> docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Enterprise
 Version:           19.03.1
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.12.5
 Git commit:        f660560464
 Built:             07/25/2019 20:59:52
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Enterprise
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.1
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.24)
  Go version:       go1.12.5
  Git commit:       f660560464
  Built:            07/25/2019 20:57:41
  OS/Arch:          windows/amd64
  Experimental:     false
PS C:\ProgramData\docker\windowsfilter> taskmgr
PS C:\ProgramData\docker\windowsfilter> docker info
Client:
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  cluster: Manage Docker clusters (Docker Inc., v1.0.1)

Server:
 Containers: 28
  Running: 28
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 0
 Images: 4
 Server Version: 19.03.1
 Storage Driver: windowsfilter
  Windows:
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: ics l2bridge l2tunnel nat null overlay transparent
  Log: awslogs etwlogs fluentd gcplogs gelf json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Default Isolation: process
 Kernel Version: 10.0 17763 (17763.1.amd64fre.rs5_release.180914-1434)
 Operating System: Windows Server Datacenter Version 1809 (OS Build 17763.678)
 OSType: windows
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 4
 Total Memory: 16GiB
 Name: nncsfc1000001
 ID: 73VB:NJAN:HXFN:R63P:DCSG:YCJT:K56A:F4MC:6NC5:KVUT:5J4C:MZ63
 Docker Root Dir: C:\ProgramData\docker
 Debug Mode: true
  File Descriptors: -1
  Goroutines: 202
  System Time: 2019-10-15T19:28:09.6416404Z
  EventsListeners: 1
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: API is accessible on http://localhost:2375 without encryption.
         Access to the remote API is equivalent to root access on the host. Refer
         to the 'Docker daemon attack surface' section in the documentation for
         more information: https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/security/#docker-daemon-attack-surface
```

i should be able to remove these stale containers which i am not able to.

Comment: try docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq)

Comment: done that as well. does not help. Command keeps on executing. I get a 'Removal in Progress'.. but nothing really happens.

Comment: @RAnand. Did you figure this one out? Seeing same issue on service Fabric